# An image grid keeps repeating?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an image grid with four different images (2x2 grid) and the grid repeats 4 times but I'm not sure why. Any thoughts?

```
<style>
.gridContainer
{
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.gridContainer img
{
    max-width: 600px;
    height: auto;
}
</style>

<div class="gridContainer">
  <img width="100%" src="cans.jpg">
  <img width="100%" src="aesthetic.jpg">
  <img width="100%" src="ts-cook.jpg">
  <img width="100%" src="ts-bowl.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58478216/css-grid-2x2-grid-always-taking-up-the-full-width-when-possible) help?

Comment: Not really, unless there's a way to make "<<div class="player">Player 1</div>" work with each image but I'm not sure how to do that. It wouldn't be "<div class="img...."</div>" would it?